# SQL Server 2008 missing install features

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, windows-server-2008

I am installing SQL Server 2008 for use with WSS 3.0, but the list of available features is truncated. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gNBW.png). Why am I missing features from this list - specifically, the management studio?

This is SQL Server 2008 Express running on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

WSS 3.0 is a separate install. Go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5719 to get it.

Comment: I have already installed WSS. I am installing SQL Server now.